# Prevent MySQL from casting float/decimals to int on data imports from Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am exporting data from Python (a `pandas.dataframe`) to MySQL using its method `.to_sql`. I further defined the data types of the data to be exported (using `dtypes` of `SQLAlchemy`), matching the data types of the target table in MySQL. The dataframe columns containing `float/decimal` values, however, arrive as `int`-type values in MySQL, although their target column in the MySQL table is defined as `DECIMAL(10,0)`. Please see my Python export code below.

```
data_df = pd.read_csv(filename_s, sep=",")
types_dict = {
    'Date': types.DATE,
    'Open': types.DECIMAL(precision=10),
    'High': types.DECIMAL(precision=10),
    'Low': types.DECIMAL(precision=10),
    'Close': types.DECIMAL(precision=10),
    'Volume': types.DECIMAL(precision=10),
    'Dividends': types.DECIMAL(precision=10),
    'Stock_splits': types.DECIMAL(precision=10),
    'Source': types.VARCHAR(length=50),
    'ISIN': types.VARCHAR(length=30)
}
table_s = 'table_name'
engine_dbconn = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost')
data_df.to_sql(table_s, engine_dbconn, schema='schema_name', if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=types_dict)
```

I am well aware, that there are workarounds, such as importing the data as a CSV-file directly from MySQL or exporting the data from Python to a varchar-only table in MySQL and transferring the data to the correct table afterwards, casting the columns as required. I am just wondering if there is a more simple/elegant way to handle this issue from within Python, as I am trying to automatize these exports to MySQL.

Comment: `DECIMAL(10, 0)` means no digits after the decimal point. So, it would *look like* an integer. [The MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) say: *If the scale is 0, DECIMAL values contain no decimal point or fractional part.*

Comment: What a stupid mistake :D changed the type in MySQL and it worked, thanks a lot!